# php mysql mysql_num_rows 2 table

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem with my code, first table is for check if the data is already inputed ( < 1 ) and from 2nd table if the data is not inputed ( > 0 )

here is my code, i cant tell what is my real problem is

edit : the problem is, my && is not working so the if only 
execute (mysql_num_rows($sql) < 1)

```
<?php 
   session_start();

   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysql_select_db("printit");


   if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$npm = $_POST['npm'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbunsil WHERE npm='$npm'");
$sqll = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE npm = '$npm'");

if((mysql_num_rows($sql) < 1) && (mysql_num_rows($sqll > 0))){
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Npm Telah Terdaftar!"); document.location="daftar.php";</script>';
}else{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $_SESSION['npm']=$row['npm'];
        echo '<script language="javascript">document.location="daftar2.php";</script>';
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Is the bracket in "if" condition correct? Instead of mysql_num_rows($sqll > 0), it should be (mysql_num_rows($sqll) > 0)

Comment: your condition isn't right